# Wrapping Galactic Longitude between (-180, +180) degrees using SphericalCircle in Astropy

Tags: python-3.x, astropy, spherical-coordinate

I am trying to plot spherical circles in galactic coordinates using the SphericalCircle module in astropy. I'm having trouble wrapping galactic longitude angles between (-180, 180) degrees instead of the default (0, 360) degrees. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from astropy.visualization.wcsaxes import SphericalCircle

glat = np.random.uniform(-90, 90, 100)
glong = np.random.uniform(-180, 180, 100)
data = np.column_stack((glong, glat)) 
gal = SkyCoord(l = data[:,0] * u.deg, b = data[:,1] * u.deg, frame='galactic')
gal_long = gal.l.wrap_at(180*u.deg).deg 

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

all_beams = []
for i in range(len(gal)):

    beam = SphericalCircle(center=(gal_long[i] * u.deg, gal[i].b.deg * u.deg), \
                          radius = 7*u.arcmin, facecolor="None",  edgecolor="black", linewidth=2)

    all_beams.append(beam)


pc = PatchCollection(all_beams, match_original=False, lw=3,  facecolor='white', 
edgecolor='k')
ax.add_collection(pc)
ax.set_xlim(-180,360)
ax.set_ylim(-90,90)
plt.show()
```

Update1: Adding More Details.
The line gal_long = gal.l.wrap_at(180*u.deg).deg wraps longitude between (-180, 180) but it looks like SphericalCircle by default changes it back to (0, 360). Is there a way to force SphericalCircle to return circles in the (-180, 180) convention?

Comment: Are you asking what math to use to wrap a value into the range [-180, 180]?

Comment: No, gal_long = gal.l.wrap_at(180*u.deg).deg wraps it between [-180,180] but it seems SphericalCircle takes it back to [0,360] which is why when I plot it looks different than I expect. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that `SphericalRepresentation` does not allow negative longitudes. You should either live with it or use `plt.plot.scatter` directly.

Comment: Using a scatter plot, is there a way to draw the marker size with radius  7 arc minutes and plot it in Galactic coordinates using matplotlib.projections?